# browse image not cropping properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop

I have created an application using **[cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)** for cropping an images. The application is working and the image is cropping, which can be seen in the preview.

After the first image is cropped, if you **load a second image** I am not able to crop. Also, when I double click on the image and then click again to drag, some unexpected movement of the image is happening.

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ANLL0csGZABtjr8pmySb?p=preview)**

**script**

```
  var $image = $('.img-container > img'),
      options = {
        modal: true,
        guides: true,
        autoCrop: false,
        dragCrop: true,
        movable: true,
        preview: '.preview',
        crop: function(data) {
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about the problem you're seeing, but this is what I see:

The second time I load an image into your Plunker the crop region disappears, but I can still click and drag a crop region.

The reason for this is the crop box element is `display:none`. This is because your old cropper has been hidden, and you need to `reset()` and `clear()` it before it can be used with the new image. You've already got the following:

```
$image.one('built.cropper', function () {
              URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL); // Revoke when load complete
            }).cropper('reset', true).cropper('replace', blobURL);
```

but your missing `clear()`

```
$image.one('built.cropper', function () {
              URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL); // Revoke when load complete
            }).cropper('reset', true).cropper('clear').cropper('replace', blobURL);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PdXFi0m2mGMbpPZ4Gb7U?p=preview) (since you asked so politely)

Comment: can you just give me a plunker